# Optimising script that does simple renaming of files

Tags: performance, bash, shell

I have recently written some code in Bash where I'm starting to program some things and I think I'm overcomplicating the script I wrote.

I'd like to make it simpler so that in future I would avoid these mistakes.

I've posted this on Stack Overflow and one user did reply that I can "simplify" multi-echoing:

> just use 1 echo command, open with a double quote on the first line and close the quote after the last one

Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Look for path when the skript is
SCRIPT_PATH=$(readlink -f "$0")

SEARCH=$(dirname "$SCRIPT_PATH")"/" 
REPLACE="../../"

echo
echo \ \ START - Replacing Absolute path to Relative
echo \ \ =================================================================
echo \ \ Info: Automatic replacement of the \>absolute\< path 
echo \ \ to \>relative\< for the Pedestrian Tool positioning result files
echo \ \ =================================================================
echo
echo \ \ "Searching for >>  $SEARCH"
echo \ \ "Replacing by  >>  $REPLACE"
echo
echo \ \ "Found in files:"
echo \ \ =================
echo

# grep - filter files where inside is scripts path name and write them down
grep -rl "${SEARCH}" --include \*.pc ./

# replace them with sed ../../
grep -rl "${SEARCH}" --include \*.pc ./ | xargs sed -i "s#${SEARCH}#${REPLACE}#g"

echo
echo \ \ END - Replacing finished...
echo \ \ =================================================================
echo \ \ =================================================================
echo
echo 
echo \ \ START - Renaming Folders by Y-Coordinate of Impactor
echo \ \ =================================================================
echo \ \ Info: Script will look into RESULTS Folder, than find directories
echo \ \ then find files in these directories and from
echo \ \ file named POSITIONING extcarc Y-Coordinate of the Impactor
echo \ \ This value is then used to rename by the: MODEL_Y\$Y-Coord
echo \ \ =================================================================
echo

# $SEARCH=path where the script is + /RESULTS/ where the results are
adresar=$SEARCH"RESULTS/"

directories=$(find $adresar*/ -type d)
echo
echo "Folders in dir: $adresar:"
echo

for d in $directories
do
    echo \ "Operations in folder: $d"

    files=$(find $d -type f )
    for f in $files; do

        fileExtension=${f##*.}

        fullPathFileName=${f%.*}
        fileName=$(basename "$fullPathFileName")

        # if Positioning_<#>.pc file
        # find line that has Target POint Coordinates string
        # example: # Target Point Coordinates  : -934.541, -100.000, 247.510
        # and extract Y-coordinate without float, that is: "-100"
        # can be 600 (without minus)
        if [[ $fileExtension == pc && $fileName == Positioning_* ]]; then
            line=$(grep "Target Point Coordinates" "$f")
            # -o (only matching) -E (extended-regexp) 
            # [^.](without dot)[0-9]+(variable number of numbers)
            STRING=$(echo $line | grep -o -E '[^.][0-9]+')
            N=3
            yCoord=$(echo $STRING | awk -v N=$N '{print $N}')
        fi
    done

    folderName=$(basename "$d" | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z') 

    if [[ $folderName != REPORT ]]; then
        echo \ \ "Dir $d renamed by Y-Coordinates of impactor"
        newFolderName=MODEL_Y$yCoord
        cd $d; cd ..

        mv $(basename "$d") $newFolderName
    fi
    echo
done
echo
echo \ \ END - Renaming complete...
echo \ \ =================================================================
echo \ \ =================================================================
echo
echo
echo \ \ START - Renaming .DSY, .msg, .THP files by folder name
echo \ \ =================================================================
echo \ \ Info: Renames .DSY, .msg, .THP files in folder RESULTS
echo \ \ by the name of parrent folder \(that is named by impactor\'s
echo \ \ Y-Coordinate \(\>\> MODEL_Y300\)
echo \ \ =================================================================
echo
directories=$(find $adresar*/ -type d)

for d in $directories
do
    echo \ "Working in folder: $d"
    files=$(find $d -type f )
    baseName=$(basename "$d")

    for f in $files; do
        cd $d
        fileExtension=${f##*.}

        fullPathFileName=${f%.*}
        fileName=$(basename "$fullPathFileName")

        Name=${baseName}.${fileExtension}  

        if [[ $fileExtension == 'pc' && $fileName != Positioning_* ]]; then
            Name=${baseName}.${fileExtension}
            mv "$f" "$Name"
            echo \ \ "Was renamed to: $Name"

        elif [ $fileExtension == 'DSY' ]; then
            Name=${baseName}.${fileExtension}
            mv "$f" "$Name"
            echo \ \ "Was renamed to: $Name"

        elif [ $fileExtension == 'THP' ]; then
            Name=${baseName}.${fileExtension}
            mv "$f" "$Name"
            echo \ \ "Was renamed to: $Name"

        elif [ $fileExtension == 'msg' ]; then
            Name=${baseName}.${fileExtension}
            mv "$f" "$Name"
            echo \ \ "Was renamed to: $Name"

        else
            echo \ \ "X Wasn't renamed."
        fi
        echo \ "====="
    done
    echo
done
echo \ \ END - Renaming complete...
echo \ \ =================================================================
echo \ \ =================================================================
echo -e "\n"
```

Comment: In addition to answer given by janos, I would consider gathering the if conditions at the end into one. The end has lots of repetitive code, which would have been solved with a function (or similar) in a programming language. But even though using bash, you should avoid repeating code.

Comment: @holroy What do you mean by that? If fileExtension pc or dsy thp or msg; then Name = base + fileExtension (which I get somehow correspondingly for the right extension)? Or you ment something else. I could write the function for "mv "$f$ "$Name$, echo \ \ "Was..." but I don
t know how to modifie the code 'Name=${baseName}.${fileExtension}' to work for **the** extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Simplifying the `echo` statements

Your question on SO suggests that you're particularly interested in simplifying all those `echo` statements.
A feature called *here-documents* can help you, for example:

```
cat <<EOF
  START - Replacing Absolute path to Relative
  =================================================================
  Info: Automatic replacement of the >absolute< path 
  to >relative< for the Pedestrian Tool positioning result files
  =================================================================

  Searching for >>  $SEARCH
  Replacing by  >>  $REPLACE

  Found in files:
  =================
EOF
```

Notice that this way you can also omit many quotes and escapes.

---

Speaking of quoting, sometimes you quote too much.
For example, instead of this:

> ```
> SEARCH=$(dirname "$SCRIPT_PATH")"/"
> ```

You could write:

```
SEARCH=$(dirname "$SCRIPT_PATH")/
```

#### Danger! Watch out for falling rocks!

Storing the output of `find` and then iterating over it is error prone.
I mean this kind of code:

> ```
> directories=$(find $adresar*/ -type d)
>
> for d in $directories
> ```

The problem with this is that it won't work with subdirectories that have a space in their name. This is because in the for loop, the shell splits the value of `$directories` by any whitespace character (space, tab, newline), not only newline, as in the output of `find`.

For example if you have a subdirectory named "a b", `find` will output it on its own line,
but when you iterate over `$directories`, the shell will split the line of "a b" in the middle.

This splitting is defined by the variable `IFS`,
you can read about it in `man bash`.

One way to make your commands safe is to set `IFS` to newline, like this:

```
oldIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'

directories=$(find $adresar*/ -type d)

for d in $directories; do
    # do work ...
done

IFS="$oldIFS"
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. So what is the right way to iterate over subdirectories if I don't want to change the IFS?

Comment: The safest way would be using `find .... -exec somescript.sh \;` but that would not be practical, as you would need to split up the scripts. I don't know a better, practical way then what I proposed, manipulating `IFS`. It would be an interesting question on UNIX SE

Comment: @SonGokussj4, As an alternative to changing the IFS, you could possibly use `find` in combinations with `xargs`, see [this answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/16758699/1548472).